# How to create a desktop-entry in Gnome?

Tags: gnome

I have installed ProM 6.8 (a process mining tool, written in Java) and after executing the command ./ProM68.sh & in a terminal, the application starts without problems.

I tried to create both a desktop-entry in Gnome 3 (on Fedora 28) or a menu-item.

This is my desktop-entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Prom
Exec=/home/bengbers/Programs/Prom/ProM68.sh %u
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false  
Categories=Development;Java;
```

After double-clicking this iscon, nothing happens.

I also tried adding an entry in the main-menu but this entry fails also.

How can I create a working desktop entry?

Ben

Comment: You should probable ask this on [linux.se].

Answer (score 0):

Prom needed a .ini file to start. After adding a path to the directory, everything worked fine.

Ben